# tensorflow optimizer outputs nan even if I set the learning rate as small as possible

Tags: python, tensorflow, optimization

Below is the code.

```
def create_train_model(hidden_nodes,num_iters):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    X=tf.placeholder(shape=(120,4),dtype=tf.float64,name='X')
    y=tf.placeholder(shape=(120,1),dtype=tf.float64,name='y')
    W1=tf.Variable(np.random.rand(4,hidden_nodes),dtype=tf.float64)
    W2=tf.Variable(np.random.rand(hidden_nodes,2),dtype=tf.float64)
    A1=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X,W1))
    U_est=tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(A1,W2))
    loss=fuloss3(U_est,y)
    optimizer=tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(4.9406564584124654e-324)
    TRAIN=optimizer.minimize(loss)
    init=tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess=tf.Session()
    sess.run(init)
    for i in range(num_iters):
        pout=sess.run(loss,feed_dict={X: Xtrain, 
                                  y: ytrain})
        sess.run(TRAIN,feed_dict={X: Xtrain, 
                                  y: ytrain})
        loss_plot[hidden_nodes][i]=sess.run(loss,feed_dict={X: Xtrain,y: 
                                                            ytrain})
        print(pout)
        weights1=sess.run(W1)
        weights2=sess.run(W2)
        print(weights1)
        print(weights2)
    print('loss (hidden nodes: %d, iterations: %d): %.2f'%(hidden_nodes,
                            num_iters,loss_plot[hidden_nodes][num_iters-1]))
    sess.close()
    return weights1, weights2
```

`print(pout)` returns a non `nan` number. While after training, the weights come out all `nan`. Even when I have set the learning rate to be the smallest possible. Why would this happen? With learning rate so small you're basically not moving the variable. The fact that the initial run on loss gave a valid result, as evident from `pout`, means that its not an issue with how I set my loss. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
W1=tf.Variable(np.random.rand(4,hidden_nodes),dtype=tf.float64)
W2=tf.Variable(np.random.rand(hidden_nodes,2),dtype=tf.float64)
```

Try this out:

```
W1 = tf.get_variable("W1", shape=..., dtype=...,
                     initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
W2 = tf.get_variable("W2", shape=..., dtype=...,
                     initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer())
```

Your weight initialization is in the [0,1] range, which are quite large weights. That's going to start the network off with wild gradient swings that are likely to throw you into a `NaN` situation.

The xavier initializer will take into account the number of inputs to a node and initialize the value such that you aren't saturating a node. In lay terms it initializes the weights intelligently depending on your architecture.

Note that there is a convoutional version of this initializer too.

Optionally, as a quick test, you could cut down the size of your weight initialization by simply multiplying the random weights by a small value such as 1e-4.

Post a comment back here if that doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. Unfortunately it still puts out `nan` weights. I will look over my loss function again, and make sure it always outputs a finite number.

Comment: I've reopened. My loss, be it weird, still gives an initial non `nan` output. Yet the slightest update completely destroys it. This means that the derivative of the loss is infinite or `nan`?

Comment: So I had a square root in my loss. Derivative of that is `0.5/sqrt(x)` if `x=0`, this will be an issue, even though `sqrt(0)` is not. So I changed it to `sqrt(x+e)`.